# Parsing LIFX headers

Tags: elixir

I have used this code to get a packet from my LIFX bulb:

```
defmodule LIFX do
  def listen(port) do
    udp_options = [:binary, {:reuseaddr, true}, { :active, false }]
    { :ok, socket } = :gen_udp.open(port, udp_options)
    do_listen(socket)
  end

  def do_listen(socket) do
    case :gen_udp.recv(socket, 0) do
      { :ok, { _ip, _port, data } } ->
        IO.inspect(data)
    end
  end
end

LIFX.listen(56700)
```

One packet of data I have received by doing this is:

```
data = <<41, 0, 0, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 115, 213, 0, 249, 20, 0, 0, 76, 73, 70, 88, 86, 50, 0, 0, 196, 240, 247, 239, 158, 36, 38, 20, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 124, 221, 0, 0>>
```

I am trying to parse this by following [LIFX's Header Description](http://lan.developer.lifx.com/docs/header-description) documentation, using this code:

```
data = <<41, 0, 0, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 115, 213, 0, 249, 20, 0, 0, 76, 73, 70, 88, 86, 50, 0, 0, 196, 240, 247, 239, 158, 36, 38, 20, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 124, 221, 0, 0>>
<< s :: unsigned-little-integer-size(16),
  origin :: unsigned-little-integer-size(8),
  tagged,
  addressable,
  protocol :: unsigned-little-integer-size(16),
  payload :: bytes >> = data
```

However, this gives me a seemingly incorrect value for `tagged` of `84`. The LIFX docs say that this should be boolean, so I'm expecting either 1 or 0; not 84.

What am I doing wrong here to get this wrong value?

Also: when I change the code to this:

```
<< s :: unsigned-little-integer-size(16),
  origin :: unsigned-little-integer-size(8),
  tagged :: unsigned-little-integer-size(1),
  addressable :: unsigned-little-integer-size(1),
  protocol :: unsigned-little-integer-size(16),
  payload :: bytes >> = data
```

This tells me:

```
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: <<41, 0, 0, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 115, 213, 0, 249, 20, 0, 0, 76, 73, 70, 88, 86, 50, 0, 0, 196, 240, 247, 239, 158, 36, 38, 20, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 124, 221, 0, 0>>
```

That leads me to thinking that I've done something wrong with the parsing of the code. I think this second chunk of code is closer to an answer, but it doesn't work obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in binary pattern matching.

```
data = <<41, 0, 0, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 115, 213, 0, 249, 20, 0, 0, 76, 73, 70, 88, 86, 50, 0, 0, 196, 240, 247, 239, 158, 36, 38, 20, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 124, 221, 0, 0>>
<< s :: unsigned-little-integer-size(16),
  origin :: unsigned-little-integer-size(8),
  tagged,
  addressable,
  protocol :: unsigned-little-integer-size(16),
  payload :: bytes >> = data
```

The sizes, you specify are always in bits, if there is no size, it defaults to 8 (one byte).

```
iex(1)> <<< a, b :: bytes>> = <<1,2,3>>
<<1, 2, 3>>
iex(1)> a
1
iex(1)> b
<<2, 3>>
```

So in your case, you should use:

```
<< s :: unsigned-little-integer-size(16),
   origin :: unsigned-little-integer-size(2),
   tagged :: size(1),
   addressable :: size(1),
   protocol :: size(12),
   source :: size(32),
   payload :: bytes >> = data
```

Note sizes on tagged, addressable and protocol. You can also specify endianness, like for origin.

When parsing, make sure, that the size of binary matches the size specified in packet header. Otherwise, you should build a mechanism, that is able to parse packets in chunks.

[More info about binary pattern matching](http://www.zohaib.me/binary-pattern-matching-in-elixir/).

EDIT for question followup:

Binary sizes need to match. For example, if you have 3 bits only, than you have to have three bits total in sizes in pattern match.

```
<<a :: size(1), b :: size(2)>> =  <<2 :: size(3)>>
```

`payload :: bytes` means, that it will match anything, that has size divisible by 8. In my answer 16 and 32 are obviously divisible by 8 and the rest is 2 + 1 + 1 + 12 = 16 bits.

In your edit, you have 16 and 32, but there are those 2 bits "hanging", which makes the pattern match fail.

Receiving code is correct. You can check that by hand. The first byte 41 actually matches the size of binary and so on.

Comment: Please see amendment to the code which uses `unsigned-little-integer-size(1)` and see how it fails.

Comment: @RyanBigg I believe the total of matched _bits_ should be divisible by 8, so `protocol :: unsigned-little-integer-size(12)` (note 12 instead of 16) and `origin :: unsigned-little-integer-size(2)` (2 instead of 8) should do the trick. The header is precisely described by the link given in OP.

Comment: Thanks @tkowal! I get it now.